# Custom Content on Sidebar of Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, content-management-system, magento-1.7

Sup Stackers!

I need your help dearly. I'm pretty much a beginner when it comes to Magento. I would like to display a custom set of links on my page sidebar, the sidebar that holds blocks such as Categories, Compare Products etc. I've tried the following:

`<reference name="right">
<block type="cms/block" name="right.permanent.callout">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>favourites</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>`

No result. The above references a cms static block I've created that just contains a UL of links. The indentifier for the block is favourites. Whenever I try to get the unordered list to show on the page by including the above in the CMS page Layout XML via the Admin panel, I get nothing happening at all. One thing to note is that, as a test, I deleted all the content that was currently in my home pages Layout XML and it changed nothing, all the sidebar content still remained.

After trying about 10 different alternatives, I'm still no closer to getting the to work. Anyone got any ideas on how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks like what it should be to get this working. A few things to check is the "name" attribute and caching. Give the block a unique name, such a "favourites." You can also add a "before" or "after" to position this block exactly where you want to on the sidebar, just reference the block name that you want it to appear before or after.

```
<reference name="right">
<block type="cms/block" name="favourites" before="-">
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>favourites</block_id></action>
</block>
</reference>
```

This should get it working. You mentioned that you removed all the code from the Layout Update XML without any changes taking effect. I don't think caching is your problem but I just want to mention it since it's still a possibility. It may have to do with how the default code is commented out, so all you're doing is removing code that isn't being applied to the layout. Hopefully this helps because I think you're right there, good luck!

Comment: While this is an awesome answer, it still hasn't worked :\ You mention something about the original code being mentioned out, what code are you referring too?

Comment: Sorry you couldn't get it working, the code I'm referring to is from your quote "I deleted all the content that was currently in my home pages Layout XML and it changed nothing, all the sidebar content still remained." What I meant is by default, Magento adds this XML code but despite doing so it's also commented out by default. So even if you remove this code, you won't see any difference. What you can do is move out the <reference name="right"> block out of the commented code and see if that makes a difference to your sidebar

Comment: Also because the block of code worked for me, check your caching. If you're developing the site you can disable caching for the time being to make sure this is not the issue. You can also do some quick tests while you're in the Layout Update XML for home. How about try placing the block in the main content block by changing the reference name to "content". Or try loading the footer_links block by changing the name and block_id to "footer_links". At which point if you don't see any changes, double check to make sure you're not entering the code after the <!--

Comment: Ok, I tried placing the block in the content reference and it worked! However, when I then tried the block in the right reference, it failed to show yet again. At a complete loss now :\

Comment: That's good, that tells us something. Now the thing to check is the "Page Layout" for home. For "Layout" what do you have selected? You'll need the "2 columns with right bar".

It also occurred to me that maybe you want to apply this block to every page in the right column. In which case the easy way is to include this block reference to your page.xml in the layout folder.

Comment: Sorted it! I altered the 2columns-left.php page within the template folder and hard coded the HTML of the block into that. Thanks for the help @HiRayLo!